# Ordenar elementos responsive con css

Tags: html, css, responsive

Estoy haciendo una pantalla de carga para una pagina web y cuando voy jugando con la resolución y vista Mobile, los 3 elementos que tengo se me desacomodan bastante.

Mas que nada el elemento "bamboo" no se posiciona por encima de las letras.

Les dejo el código, si me pueden orientar por donde podria estar el error.

https://codepen.io/oren-diaz/pen/BaKzWVK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algunos ajustes que pude reconocer al ajustar varias resoluciones diferentes. algunos de estos puedes ajustarlos aun mas dependiendo del resultado final que desees.

Darle a la imagen un valor maximo en porcentaje (de acuerdo a la relacion de aspecto)

```
.bamboo{
    max-width: 50%;
    max-height: 30%;
}
```

Evitar que el texto se corte , mantenerlo centrado

```
#nombrePuraVida{
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: center;
}
```

La seccion de los puntos, ajustar la posicion en porcentaje;

```
.wrapper{
    top:80%;
}
```

https://codepen.io/fraigo/pen/eYZzvwj

Comment: el max-width: 50%; lo cambie a 30% y se centro perfecto en el medio de la frase "pura vida" tanto para full pantalla como para celular. Muchas gracias